# StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory does not go through script

Tags: javascript, solr

I'm trying to test my code for solr.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.
I have these files below.

solrconfig.xml

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="classificationChain" default="true">
  <processor class="solr.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="script">update-script.js</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

schema file

```
<fieldType name="strings" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true" docValues="true" />
<field name="classification" type="strings" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

update-script.js

```
function processAdd(cmd) {
  doc = cmd.solrDoc;
  id = doc.getFieldValue("id");
  doc.setField("classification", ["HISTORY", "MUSIC"]);
  logger.info("Processed: " + id);
}

function processDelete(cmd) {
    // no-op
}

function processMergeIndexes(cmd) {
    // no-op
}

function processCommit(cmd) {
    // no-op
}

function processRollback(cmd) {
    // no-op
}

function finish() {
    // no-op
}
```

When I run the update, documents don't have classification field value and it's not logged too.

Comment: How are you triggering your update-chain? I'm not familiar with the `default` parameter that you've given (and can't seem to find any documentation about it)

Comment: @MatsLindh Default parameter doesnt really do anything here. Even without that, its still not working

Comment: Yes, but _how_ are you asking for the chain to be invoked? If you're not asking for it by name, it won't be invoked.

Comment: @MatsLindh I have this in my solrconfig.xml `<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="update.chain">languageChain</str>
        <str name="update.chain">classificationChain</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
`

Comment: I don't think you can define multiple chains to run like that. You'll have to create one combined chain that performs all the operations as one.